# Pagination of search results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I have a form where user is able to choose search options. When user clicks "Search" button,
an appropriate GET controller's action is invoked:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearcherViewModel model, int pageNo=1)
        {
         var results = xService.GetSearchResults(model);
         return View("Index", results);
}
```

GetSearchResults method does not connect to the database, but instead it call some third party web service. This however is not the main issue.

Therefore, the url can look as follows:

http://localhost/Search?startDate=20120210&offerType=3&foodId=4&&Destination=456

How can I implement a pagination of  search results? In particular, how should I construct the page numbers and how to use my model?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda depends on how much stuff you are paginating. If it is small then you can hold the whole thing in javascript memory using preloading and then paginate based on the javascript objects. If you are looking at potentially tens of thousands or more of items to paginate, then you may consider preloading part of that and then using ajax to load pages later on depending on how the user navigates.

Comment: well, there will be rather thousands of items, but how my links should look like, even when using AJAX?

Comment: but how this should work? How can I create link for pagination? How can I know what kind of result conditions are chosen when I click on a particular page?